# Decal Rotating Wrongly When Following Curve

Tags: image, curve-modifier

I am attempting to get a decal to follow a predefined curve. By this, I mean it should follow the path specified by the curve upon changing the Y-value, where -Y is forward as standard.

1. I first set the decal at the correct height from the path and set it to have the same pivot using the 3D cursor, which is, in this case, at [5, 0, 0.3]
2. I then apply the curve modifier, using the Y-axis as the axis of rotation.

My result is a distorted, incorrectly rotated decal.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? What went wrong?

**BEFORE APPLYING MODIFIER**

[image: Before Applying Modifier]

**AFTER APPLYING MODIFIER**
[image: After Applying Modifier]

EDIT: Added example file.

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Added. Thank you.

Comment: You need to put the origin at the geometry of the object and then Alt G to bring back the object at the same location as the curve's origin. Then in Edit mode rotate it 90° on Y if you want it flat?

Comment: This does work, I checked - before I accept the answer - but why does the decal need to be rotated 90 degrees? It should have the same orientation as the curve.

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm always lost with the orientations  ^^

Comment: notice that the curve normal direction matters in the object direction (in Edit mode, right click > Switch Direction). The 90° may have to do with the tilt of the curve?

Comment: One final question: can a vertical offset be added to the position of the object relative to the curve?

Comment: I'm not sure how you could do it, what is the purpose exactly, why not change the curve radius in that case? If you move the object on Z it will get deformed

Comment: I have resolved it by creating two curves, one scaled larger than the other, for two rotating objects. The decal should sit on the surface of the other object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the origin at the geometry of the object and then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to bring back the object at the same location as the curve's origin. Then in *Edit* mode rotate it 90° on Y if you want it flat (I guess it has to do with the curve vertices tilt, you can tweak the *Tilt* value in the N panel, also note that you can invert the normals with <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Switch Direction*).